# webserver Can we redirect a page to a client localhost page in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know as to whether we can redirect a server page to client localhost page and read a JSON data in a particular directory.
To read JSON data.

```
$data['result'] = $this->Json_model->get_data_list($table_name,$tab_id,$tab_field,$order_field,$order_by,$filter_field,$filter_value);

//print_r($data['result']);

$output = json_encode( $data['result'] );

$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
//$this->output->set_output($output);
```

Comment: are they running a webserver on their local machine?

Comment: Yes we have 2 projects one in server and other in localhost and I want to transfer my data from server to localhost database